# How can I play a video file on raw image with a loop smooth?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-player

The problem is when it finish playing it's waiting like 1 second before starting playing over again.
I want it to loop playing nonstop without a delay.

If I uncheck the loop in the video player settings it will play it once if it's checked it will play it over again but with a small delay when it's getting to the end of the video and starting play it again.

This is a screenshot of the scene settings the video player :

[image: Video Player settings]

This is the raw image settings :

[image: Raw Image settings]

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, it's quite hacky but the best solution i found was simply to have two video players, one behind the other, when one finishes swap their position and start the other one playing.
The problem is the time to stream the beginning of the video and I think it is unavoidable...